# water tank drains water?

Tags: water, hot-water, corrosion, water-tank

The house came with this hot water tank. As you can see there is a white vertical pipe. I noticed it drips a water right on the floor.

Also, as you may notice, the tank has signs of corrosion at the bottom (probably result of water dripping etc.). Is it a defected installation? What is the right way to have this installed/fixed? How do I know if tank's corrosion is really bad and requires the tank replacement?

[image: Water Heater Tank]
[image: TPR valve]

Comment: What is the manufacture date on the WH?

Comment: Do not get confused with some of the wordy answers, the purpose of those is to cover all angels (it could be this or could be that), and somehow be right. You have a very simple problem. You do not need expansion tank. Just replace the valve on the top. Its function is safety release only, so it should not be leaking.

Comment: Be sure to check the edit history of the short, simplistic answers. Especially when you replace the TPR and the leak continues.

Answer (score 4):

While it's not out of the question that "all is lost" with your current tank as the conclusion others leap to, it's really not the most likely situation.

**Temperature-Pressure Relief** valves (**TPR**) drip for various reasons, and the dripping from that is very likely the primary cause of the corrosion, rather than the tank being rotted out and dead.

Trivial diagnostic before even fixing anything - place a bucket there to catch the drips, see if the floor dries up - if so, no leak from the tank itself, solve the problem making the valve drip, flush the tank, maybe replace the anode rod, get quite a few more years from the tank, most likely.

Reasons to drip or actuate:

- Over temperature (very rare - and not usually a drip.)
- Over pressure (common)
- Valve failing (common)

Overtemperature comes from the heat (thermostatic control of element or burner) not shutting off, and won't be a drip, it will be a steaming gusher.

Excess pressure is usually from not having an **expansion tank**, or having a failed expansion tank. Cold water expands when heated, and if no water is being used and there's no functional expansion tank, and the supply has a **check valve** or something that acts like a check valve (such as a **Pressure Reducing Valve - PRV**) the pressure in the house system rises as cold water is heated. Easily solved by adding an expansion tank or replacing a failed one.

Excess pressure can also be from excess incoming water pressure, indicating a need for a PRV, or service/replacement of a failed PRV.

Valve failing is observed when you have drippage, but a pressure gauge shows no excess pressure. Replace with the equivalent valve, but a new, working one. If you have had some actuations due to overpressure it's not uncommon for the valve to fail to seal fully when pressure drops again. Likewise if someone has manually actuated the valve "to test it" (which isn't much good as a test, and may well make it leak, so...)

It drips **on the floor** because it's not supposed to drip at all in normal use, and you are supposed to notice and take corrective action when it does drip (or spew considerably more than a drip.) *If you had the home inspected before purchase, (which I infer to be perhaps recent as you say "the house came with...") get your money back if the inspector missed noting this obvious issue. If you've owned the house for a long time, discuss not noticing this sooner with the person in the mirror.*

You can have it drip in an open drip pan, but the code issue is that it should be noticable, not go unnoticed down a drain when it actuates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments! I updated my question and added the photo of upper side of the tank. Is this the TPR valve that need to be replaced? I tested as was suggested in one of comments, and can confirm that the tank itself does not leak water (which is good).

Comment: Yes, that's the TPR valve.

Answer (score 1):

The Overpressure release vale on to off the boiler may be defective (and it is leaking), located at the end of the PVC pipe.

Continuous dripping on the water tank hosing, has created the rust. I might be the housing only and not the tank.

Depending further investigation, you might have to replace the tank, and get new over pressure valve.

Comment: The TPR may be defective or possibly if the house has a pressure reducing valve, it may be defective,     If not, the OP should put a simple pressure gauge on a hose bib and see what pressures they are dealing with.     Ruskes, you may be right in that the tank itself is leaking.  If thats the case you are certainly right it's beyond repair.   But if the TPR has been leaking a lot and just rusted the casing, maybe not.  Let's get this diagnosed properly and not just throw parts at it.